# Handling GearVR Controller events in AFrame

Tags: aframe

So, I should start out with the warning that I'm new to AFrame, (though not to programming, game programming, or Javascript). I'm currently trying to put together a simple scene with basic GearVR controller interaction.

When I say "basic interaction", I mean I have the little starter scene that you get when you follow the [official tutorial](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/guides/building-a-basic-scene.html), and I'm just trying to expand that out, such that when you press the trigger, (and specifically the trigger, not just any button), the little text component has it's text value changed.

To make a long story short -- my code isn't working. Despite the fact that I add the event listener in the component init function, (and I've confirmed that init is being called), the listener callback never seems to be invoked. If I had to guess, I'd say that the entity I've attached 'laser-controls' to isn't emitting the 'triggerdown' event, but I'm not sure how to confirm that.   Here are the relevant pieces:

```js
AFRAME.registerComponent('gearvr-trigger', {
  schema: {
    textValue: {
      default: "Hello WebVR!"
    }
  },

  init: function() {
    var message_box = document.querySelector('#message');
    var el = this.el;

    el.addEventListener('triggerdown', function(evt) {
      message_box.setAttribute('value', this.data.textValue);
    });

  }


});
```

```html
  <a-text id='message' value="Hello, A-Frame!" color="#BBB"
    position="-0.9 0.2 -3" scale="1.5 1.5 1.5">
  </a-text>


<a-box gearvr-trigger='textValue: "New Text Value";' src='#boxTexture' position='0 2 -5' rotation='0 45 45' scale='2 2 2'>
  <a-animation attribute='position' to='0 2.5 -5' direction='alternate' dur='2000' repeat='indefinite'></a-animation>
  <a-animation attribute="scale" begin="mouseenter" dur="300" to="2.3 2.3 2.3"></a-animation>
  <a-animation attribute="scale" begin="mouseleave" dur="300" to="2 2 2"></a-animation>
  <a-animation attribute="rotation" begin="click" dur="2000" to="360 405 45"></a-animation>
</a-box>
<a-entity raycaster='far: 100; showLine: true;' line='color: red;' laser-controls></a-entity>
```

If someone with more experience than me sees what I'm doing wrong, that would be great, but I'd also be happy if you could just point me at some decent code examples of responding to GearVR controller events.

Comment: Do they need to be pointing at the box and press trigger, or do they just need to press trigger while pointing anywhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have noted, the reason you're not picking up the `'triggerdown'` events in your custom component is that these events are emitted by the controller entity (`a-entity[laser-controls]` in this case), and they bubble just as in the standard DOM, (which would be next to `a-scene` in this case), so `a-box` is not seeing them.

When you combine information about controller buttons and the controller's relation to other entities in the scene (e.g. pointing with a laser or collisions), I like to call that a gesture. The `laser-controls` component provides basic gesture interpretation, but I have created the [`super-hands` package for rich gesture interpretation](https://github.com/wmurphyrd/aframe-super-hands-component) including what you require: button discrimination.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.7.1/aframe.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/super-hands/dist/super-hands.min.js"></script>
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent('gearvr-trigger', {
  schema: {
    textValue: {
      default: "Hello WebVR!"
    }
  },

  init: function() {
    var message_box = document.querySelector('#message');
    var el = this.el;
    var triggerResponse = function (evt) {
      if (evt.detail.state === 'clicked') {
        message_box.setAttribute('value', this.data.textValue);
      }
    }
    el.addEventListener('stateadded', triggerResponse.bind(this));

  }

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a-scene>
<a-assets>
  <a-mixin id="point-laser" raycaster='far: 100; showLine: true;' line='color: red;'></a-mixin>
</a-assets>
<a-text id='message' value="Hello, A-Frame!" color="#BBB"
    position="-0.9 0.2 -3" scale="1.5 1.5 1.5">
  </a-text>


<a-box clickable="startButtons: triggerdown, mousedown; endButtons: triggerup, mouseup" gearvr-trigger='textValue: "New Text Value";' src='#boxTexture' position='0 2 -5' rotation='0 45 45' scale='2 2 2'>
  <a-animation attribute='position' to='0 2.5 -5' direction='alternate' dur='2000' repeat='indefinite'></a-animation>
  <a-animation attribute="scale" begin="hover-start" dur="300" to="2.3 2.3 2.3"></a-animation>
  <a-animation attribute="scale" begin="hover-end" dur="300" to="2 2 2"></a-animation>
  <a-animation attribute="rotation" begin="grab-end" dur="2000" to="360 405 45"></a-animation>
</a-box>
<a-entity progressive-controls="maxLevel: point; pointMixin: point-laser" ></a-entity>
</a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

For the controller, `progressive-controls` auto-detects the controller and sets up the laser pointer like `laser-controls`, but using `super-hands` gesture interpretation (it also provides cursor-like input for desktop/cardboard users).

```
<a-entity progressive-controls="maxLevel: point; pointMixin: point-laser"></a-entity>
```

For the target entity, `clickable` activates it as a gesture receiving component and defines which button events it will accept (you can remove the mouse ones if you don't want cross-platform support). The animation trigger events were also updatedaa to work with `super-hands`.

```
<a-box clickable="startButtons: triggerdown, mousedown; endButtons: triggerup, mouseup" gearvr-trigger='textValue: "New Text Value";' ...>
...
<a-animation attribute="scale" begin="hover-start" dur="300" to="2.3 2.3 2.3"></a-animation>
<a-animation attribute="scale" begin="hover-end" dur="300" to="2 2 2"></a-animation>
<a-animation attribute="rotation" begin="grab-end" dur="2000" to="360 405 45"></a-animation>
```

For your custom reaction component, I changed it to react to state changes, which is how `clickable` communicates that is has received an acceptable gesture. I also resolved a scoping issue that you would have caught once you had the events triggering this.

```
    var triggerResponse = function (evt) {
      if (evt.detail.state === 'clicked') {
        message_box.setAttribute('value', this.data.textValue);
      }
    }
    el.addEventListener('stateadded', triggerResponse.bind(this));
```

Comment: All the other answers on this thread have been good, but this one was the most thorough. I'll definitely be checking out super-hands!

Answer (score 0):

Try setAttribute('text', 'value, 'whatever you wanted') ?

Comment: That's what this bit is doing:

 el.addEventListener('triggerdown', function(evt) {
      message_box.setAttribute('value', this.data.textValue);
    });

Comment: Also, the triggerdown event may fire on the entity that has laser-controls attached, which is not your message box entity

Comment: Right, I guess I should be a little more clear about what's supposed to happen here. In the scene, there's a floating cube. Upon pointing at the cube and triggering, I want to see the text message updated.  Therefore, I attached the component to the cube that will be clicked and then just do a DOM lookup to find the text.

Comment: It looks like you have triggerdown listener on the a-box, but not the a-entity with laser-controls... I may be remembering wrong, but I seem to recall that the event that cursor/raycaster fires on the intersected element is not triggerdown, but (eventually) click...

Comment: I'm basing the event name on this:

https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/gearvr-controls.html

As I understand it, this component is wrapped by laser-controls, so shouldn't it emit the gearvr-controls event?

Comment: The triggerdown event will fire on the a-entity with laser-controls (that gets gearvr-controls).  But you want the event that goes to the target, and if you look at the docs for the cursor component that laser-controls uses, you'll see what I mean by click

Comment: Steve, any chance it's a scope issue? Trying out your code with a basic click event causes an error on this.data.textValue because 'this' is referring to the element instead of the the component. If you try creating a 'self' variable or using an es6 () => function does it work? Here's an example:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/a-frame-event-listener-scope

Answer (score 0):

In case it's not the trigger code, it could be a scope issue:
'this' is referring to the element in the handler as opposed to the component, so this.data is undefined during the event

A potential fix:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('gearvr-trigger', {
  schema: {
    textValue: {
      default: "Hello WebVR!"
    }
  },

  init: function() {
    var message_box = document.querySelector('#message');
    var el = this.el;

    var self = this;
    el.addEventListener('triggerdown', function(evt) {
      message_box.setAttribute('value', self.data.textValue);
    });
  }
});
```

or using an arrow function

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('gearvr-trigger', {
  schema: {
    textValue: {
      default: "Hello WebVR!"
    }
  },

  init: function() {
    var message_box = document.querySelector('#message');
    var el = this.el;

    el.addEventListener('triggerdown', (evt) => {
      message_box.setAttribute('value', this.data.textValue);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The `triggerdown` event fires on the entity with the laser-controls attribute.

My code uses the `click` event and responds to either button press (unlike what you want) but implementing this pattern may nudge you forward. (It's also more on the path to cross-device operation.)  The `click` event may contain which button was pressed.

In the scene, I have:

`<a-entity laser-controls="hand: right"></a-entity>`

In a script, I register

> ```
>     AFRAME.registerComponent('cursor-listener', {
>         init: function () {
>             var lastIndex = -1;
>             var COLORS = ['purple', 'orange', 'white'];
>             this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
>                 lastIndex = (lastIndex + 1) % COLORS.length;
>                 this.setAttribute('material', 'color', COLORS[lastIndex]);
>                 console.log('I was clicked at: ', evt.detail.intersection.point);
>             });
>         }
>     });
> ```

Then I set the `cursor-listener` attribute on the target boxes:

`boxEl.setAttribute('cursor-listener', true);`

Comment: This definitely gets me a little closer...at least in the sense that I'm getting a response to the "click" event when pressing the top button. The trigger continues to be completely ignored though -- it's not even being treated like a click.  Just to be clear -- I know the trigger works in general, I use it all the time.

Comment: Yes, I forgot that laser-controls only uses the touchpad button.  You might want to use laser-controls, and monkey-patch it to use the trigger instead. Or add button configuration to laser-controls, and submit a pull request.

Comment: Actually, after fiddling with things a little bit and realizing my mistake, I found that I _was_ able to get triggerdown working with laser-controls, which makes sense if you consider that the laser-controls component does actually set up the gearvr-controls behind the scenes.